# Error Warning: PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Al crear una conexion `PDO` me sale el siguiente error:

> **Warning:** PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in

**Código**

```
<?php 

class ConexionBD{

    #Objeto PDO
        public $pdo;

        #Consulta preparada
        public $consulta;

        #Datos de la Conexion BD
        public $datosDB;

        #Estado de la conexion
        public $estadoConexion = true;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexionBD();

    }

    public function conexionBD(){
        #Se lee la ruta del archivo .ini
        $archivoCf = "../.conf/cf.php.ini";
        #Se convierte el archivo .ini a Array
        $datosDB = parse_ini_file($archivoCf,true);
        #Se Crea la cadena de Conexion obteniendo los datos del archivo .ini
        $cadenaConexion ="mysql:dbname='".$datosDB['BD']['dbNombre']."';dbname='".$datosDB['Host']['host']."'";

        #Se obtiene el Usuario y la contraseña de la Conexion
        $usuario = $datosDB['Credenciales']['usuario'];
        $contrasena = $datosDB['Credenciales']['contrasena'];



        try{
            #Se establece la Conexion
            $this->pdo = new PDO($cadenaConexion, $usuario, $contrasena);
            $estadoConexion = true;
            echo 'Conectado';
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
            $estadoConexion = false;
            echo 'Error al Conectar';
        }

    }

    public function cerrarConexion(){
        $this->pdo = null;
    }
}

new ConexionBD();


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu cadena de conexión está mal:

```
$cadenaConexion ="mysql:dbname='".$datosDB['BD']['dbNombre']."';dbname='".$datosDB['Host']['host']."'";
```

Repites dos veces el valor para `dbname`. Y, dado que después de `dbname` puedes pasarle el charset seguido de punto y coma, interpreta que quieres establecer una charset desconocido (el nombre de tu base de datos como charset). Además el `host` no lo estás pasando en el lugar que corresponde.

Puedes corregir el código así, creando además un DSN más limpio (recomiendo también que trates de usar variables más cortas para cosas sencillas).

```
public function conexionBD(){
    #Se lee la ruta del archivo .ini
    $archivoCf = "../.conf/cf.php.ini";
    #Se convierte el archivo .ini a Array
    $datosDB = parse_ini_file($archivoCf,true);
    #Se Crea la cadena de Conexion obteniendo los datos del archivo .ini

    $dbName=$datosDB['BD']['dbNombre'];
    $host=$datosDB['Host']['host'];
    $charset='utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName;charset=$charset";

    #Se obtiene el Usuario y la contraseña de la Conexion
    $usr = $datosDB['Credenciales']['usuario'];
    $pwd = $datosDB['Credenciales']['contrasena'];

    try{

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        #Se establece la Conexion
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);
        $estadoConexion = true;
        echo 'Conectado';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
        $estadoConexion = false;
        echo 'Error al Conectar';
    }

}
```

Aquí he aplicado algunas prácticas recomendadas:

- Establecer precisamente un charset adecuado, de modo que no tengamos problemas con los acentos y símbolos especiales que vengan en nuestras consultas.
- Pasar un array `$options` al constructor de PDO con dos configuraciones esenciales:

  - es preciso apagar las preparaciones emuladas, que vienen encendidas por defecto y pueden ser usadas por hackers para emular sentencias preparadas y colar inyección SQL (expliqué eso con detalle en mi respuesta sobre el tema a una pregunta planteada aquí hace ya algún tiempo).
  - es conveniente establecer `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` y tener mucho cuidado con el manejo de errores. Si esto no se hace bien y hay algún fallo creando la conexión, se escribirá en el log de errores las credenciales de conexión (usuario y contraseña incluidos). Los archivos log son de los preferidos de los hackers para encontrar información sensible. Una recomendación al respecto es usar contraseñas largas (30 o más caracteres). Hay que evitar como ya dije que se escriba la contraseña en el log, pero si esto ocurriese y la contraseña es larga se truncará, no se escribirá completa.